# Magento 2 + Checkout Billing address Telephone Number Validation

Tags: magento2.3, billing-address, custom-validation

I have created a plugin for billing address phone number validation, but it's giving me an error

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: dataScopePrefix in /var/www/html/test/vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php on line 139
```

below is my code

> Custom\BillingAddress\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="validate_telephone_checkout_layoutprocessor" type="Custom\BillingAddress\Plugin\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="100"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

plugin -

> Custom\BillingAddress\Plugin\LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\BillingAddress\Plugin;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * Telephone number validation
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
        )) {
            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                ['telephone']['validation'] = ['phoneLax' => true];
            }
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You added wrong validation type. Please replace validation type
> "phoneLax" to "validate-phoneLax" as shown in following code:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\BillingAddress\Plugin;

class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * Telephone number validation
     *
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array $jsLayout
    ) {
        if (isset($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']
        )) {
            foreach ($jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                     ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'] as $key => $payment) {
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$key]['children']['form-fields']['children']
                ['telephone']['validation'] = ['validate-phoneLax' => true];    // Change validation type 'phoneLax' to 'validate-phoneLax'
            }
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working !!!

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this in Magento 2.4 but not working because "Process" method is no more available in Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor. Basically "LayoutProcessor" class has been removed and instead "\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor\Interceptor" class has been introduced.